# Как сделать проверку отправителя discord.py?

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands



class User():
    
    def __init__(self, name, points):
        self.name = name
        self.points = points
    
    def get_points(self):
        print(self.points)
    
    def add_points(self, number):
        self.points += number
    
    def remove_points(self, number):
        self.points -= number
        if self.points < 0:
            self.points = 0

user1 = User('Egor', 0)




bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot has connected')



@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def add(ctx, number, member: discord.Member = None):
    #ЕСЛИ УКАЗАЛИ ТАКОГО-ТО ЧЕЛОВЕКА, ДОБАВИТЬ ОЧКИ В ЮЗЕР 1, ЕСЛИ ТАКОГО, В ЮЗЕР 2 И Т.Д
    await ctx.send(f"Balance of {member} was increased by 100 pts!")
```

Суть в чем. Нужно создать бота, который при вводе команд будет начислять или убирать очки у людей. Для этого я создал класс и создам несколько экземпляров. Если есть другие идеи как это лучше реализовать, буду благодарен, но я новичок так что слишком сложное не предлагайте) Основной вопрос заключается в том, как сделать проверку пользователя. То есть я например пишу в чате >add 100 @Ivan и как мне узнать, что указан именно Иван и начислить ему очки после команды? И приемлем ли способ сохранения всех операций в обычном файле, что бы значения не сбрасывались после каждого перезапуска программы?

Comment: в этом то и проблема. Когда я пишу if discord.Member == '@ilya' и в сообщении действительно @ilya проверка не проходит

Comment: с sqlite тоже проблемы постоянные... нужно всю документацию читать получается, что бы во всем прям разобраться. А проект который я хочу сдлеать того не стоит, не коммерческий и т.д так чисто для друзей

Comment: @Forever_tilted, если вы хотите сделать "проверку" пользователя, то проверяйте id пользователей, либо получите пользователя и сравните его с тем, кого указали при вводе команды. Также вы не правильно сделали проверку, например `if member.id == id_пользователя`.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное!!! мне как раз нужна была вот эта строчка: if member.id == id_пользователя. Теперь все работает!!